# splitting a file with diff conflict markers into separate files

Tags: mercurial, diff, meld

I use a dcvs (mercurial) and had a merge conflict a few minutes ago. For various reasons, I can't have it just open meld when it has a conflict, so I let it add conflict markers to the file:

```
<<<<<<< local
    ...
=======
>>>>>>> other
```

And so on. When I open this file up in meld, it of course can't handle it, because it's looking for several files.

How do I split it into file.local, file.other, and file.base so that I can open it in meld? Is there a better way?